# Как получить привязанные к ManyToMany filed элементы через _set ? Django

Tags: python, django

Раньше я хорошо это делал, но сейчас не могу вспомнить.

models.py:

```
class Tovar(models.Model):
    idtov = models.CharField("ID товара", max_length=30, default="default")
    name = models.CharField("Название товара", max_length=400, default="default")


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Товар"
        verbose_name_plural = "Товары"
        ordering = ('id',)




class Checks(models.Model):
    iddoc = models.CharField("Id Чека", max_length=30)
    tovars = models.ManyToManyField("Tovar", verbose_name="Товары в чеке", related_name="tovar")
    createtime = models.DateTimeField("Дата", auto_now_add=True)
#   count = ...   Будем брать из Checks.objects.get(pk=pk).tovars
    summa = models.FloatField()


    def __str__(self):
        return f"Id чека: {self.iddoc}"

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Чек"
        verbose_name_plural = "Чеки"
        ordering = ("createtime",'id')
```

Я хочу получить из объекта Checks все товары, привязанные к нему через related name.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй создать функцию в модели Checks(get_all_tovar, к примеру). Дальше легко:

```
return self.tovars.all()
```

Comment: Вроде можно было и не создавать функцию, а через related name обращаться вроде

Comment: Просто related name - это для обратного разрешения, то есть, чтобы через Tovar обращаться к Checks. А тебе вроде нужно через саму модель Checks все tovars вытащить. Это, насколько я знаю,  делается напрямую.